# C++, pass generic array by pointer, inheritence, error: no operator which takes a right-hand operand

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have to implement a generic binary search function for a class project. The test file, and header file(class definitions) have been provided for me, and cannot be modified.

I am able to get it to work with 2 of the 3 test object types I've tested it with, which is what has me stumped, and i don't know how to troubleshoot further.

Here is my algorithm:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
int binarySearch(T* list[], const V& searchValue,
    const int firstIndex, const int lastIndex) { 

        int half = (firstIndex + lastIndex) /2;

        // if not completly split down already
        if(firstIndex != lastIndex && half != 0){ 

            if(searchValue < *list[half]){  
                // lower half of array
                binarySearch(list, searchValue, firstIndex, half); 
            }
            else if(searchValue > *list[half]){     
                // upper half of array
                binarySearch(list, searchValue, ++half, lastIndex); 
            }
        }
        else if(searchValue == *list[half]){
            return half; // found it
        }
        return -1; // didnt find it
}
```

Here are my 3 arrays of objects test cases:

```
// pointers to child class objects
Customer* customer[] = { new Customer(1002, 100000.50, "F4", "L1"),
    new Customer(1004, 45000.90, "F1", "L3"),
    new Customer(1003, 120000, "F3", "L2"),
    new Customer(1001, 340000, "F2", "L4")
};

// pointers to child class objects
Employee* employee[] = { new Employee(102, 65000, "F2", "L1"),
    new Employee(104, 45000, "F4", "L3"),
    new Employee(103, 120000, "F1", "L2"),
    new Employee(101, 35000, "F3", "L4")
};

// pointers to parent class objects
Person* person[] = { customer[0],
    customer[3],
    employee[3],
    employee[0],
    employee[2],
    customer[1],
    employee[1],
    customer[2]
};
```

I am calling the function with each object like so:

```
// Search the customer array. -> WORKS
cout << endl
     << "Searching customer array for customer with cId = 1002: "
     << (binarySearch(customer, 1002, 0, 3) != -1? "found it." : "did not find it.")
     << endl;

// Search the employee array. -> WORKS
cout << "Searching employee array for employee with eId = 105: "
     << (binarySearch(employee, 105, 0, 3) != -1? "found it." : "did not find it.")
     << endl;

// Search the person array. -> OPERATOR ERRORS
cout << "Searching people array for person with name = 'Mickey Mouse': "
     << (binarySearch(person, "Mickey Mouse", 0, 7) != -1? "found it." : "did not find it.")
     << endl;
```

The search function runs fine on both the Employee, and Customer object arrays. When trying to run a search on the Person array, i get 3 errors for each of the comparison operators used, like: [binary '<' no operand which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Person'...]

I implemented the operator overloads the exact same way for all three objects from the function definitions that were where already provided. In the person class, i implemented the following overloaded operators:

```
bool operator ==(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs){
    if(lhs.getKeyValue() == rhs.getKeyValue())
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool operator <(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs){
    if(lhs.getKeyValue() < rhs.getKeyValue())
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool operator >(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs){
    if(lhs.getKeyValue() > rhs.getKeyValue())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

When doing a simplified test compare on two person objects, they compare just fine. i.e:

```
cout << "test person compare: " << ("mickey mouse" < person[1] ? "true" : "false");
```

I'm not sure where to take it from here, and direction would be much appreciated.

**Edit: Addition (Complete Person Header File):**

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace P03 {
    class Person {

    private:
        string firstName;
        string lastName;

    public:
        /* Initializes the object.
         */
        Person(const string& firstName = "na", const string& lastName = "na");

        /* Getter methods retun the field value.
         */
        string getFirstName() const;
        string getLastName() const;

        /* Returns the eid.
         */
        string getKeyValue() const;

        /* Returns the compound value: <lastName><space><firstName>
         */
        string getName() const;

        /* Setter methods, set the object.
         */
        void setFirstName(const string& firstName);
        void setLastName(const string& lastName);


        /* Returns the object formatted as:
        *  Person{ firstName=<firstName>, lastName=<lastName> }
        */
        virtual string toString() const;
    }; // end Person


    /* Displays a Person to the screen.
     * Calls the toString() method.
     */
    ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Person& person);

    /* The following relational operators compare two instances of the
     * Person class. The comparison is made on the compound value of:
     * <lastName><space><firstName>
     */
    bool operator ==(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs);
    bool operator !=(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs);
    bool operator <(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs);
    bool operator <=(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs);
    bool operator >(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs);
    bool operator >=(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs);

} // end namespace P03

#endif
```

Comment: You're not passing `Person` objects to the search, you're passing a string.  How are your comparison functions (like `(searchValue < *list[half])`) working?

Comment: Those are my thoughts exactly, but the other two work! I'm so confused. I would think they would all need the below solution now that i think about it to work.

Comment: Can u show the header file?

Comment: Sure, i added it at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1):

You have no way to convert a string to a person, so lines like this fail:

```
        if(searchValue < *list[half]){
```

You'll get better debug if you change it temporarily to:

```
        if (T(searchValue) < *list[half]){
```

That's the only way this code can work because the only `operator<` that can take `*list[half]` would need a `const T &` on the other side.

Comment: Your awesome dude, thanks. Not sure i understand why the other two classes worked without it, but they all work now. May the Schwartz be with you.

Comment: Sorry, jumped to conclusions, they compile, but it doesn't actually do the comparison right, but re-reading your post makes me realize you meant for this to help me debug, and thanks, it is helping me look at the objects now with the debugger.